# AppCompat Navigation Drawer not letting me to focus any EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am creating an application for pre-L (exactly API 9+) devices using AppCompat support library.
The problem I have is related to AppCompat's Navigation drawer: if I have a drawer in my layout and I am initializing it, none of the EditText elemenets in my fragments cannot be focused (they are getting fosus for a split-second, and then they lose it; the soft-keyboard is not showing up).

I am using only an activity into which I load fragments:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="?android:windowContentOverlay">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_fragment"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/scan_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_scan"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="4dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/drawer_content"/>
```

I tested the code without initializing the drawer and everything is working fine. Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what was the issue. I don't know why, probably because the touch event was going trough the drawer, I had in my code this line which was disabling any events on everything under DrawerLayout:

```
    drawer.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```